# Background image height & width does't work on IE11

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-11

That is my client website- http://rubowarkitekter.dk/
I already code to make background image height & width according to adjust screen size/100% height & 100% width. But that is not work on IE11.

My css code-

```
.home {
background: url(http://rubowarkitekter.dk/wp-content/uploads/2013/12/forside_carlsberg.jpg) center center no-repeat fixed;
background-size: cover;  
z-index: -500;  
-webkit-background-size: cover;  
-moz-background-size: cover;  
-o-background-size: cover;
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(src='.http://rubowarkitekter.dk/wp-content/uploads/2013/12/forside_carlsberg.jpg', sizingMethod='scale');/* To make IE work */
-ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(src='http://rubowarkitekter.dk/wp-content/uploads/2013/12/forside_carlsberg.jpg', sizingMethod='scale')"; /* To make IE work */  
}
```

Any idea how can i make background image to height & width 100% on IE11.

Thanks

IE11 screenshot-
[image: IE11 screenshot]

Comment: Why are you using only experimental vendor prefixed versions of the background size property?

Comment: I am not expert on css. For that reason i take that code from csstricks website. Actually i don't know how that is work-    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(src='.myimage.jpg', sizingMethod='scale');/* To make IE work */
-ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(src='myimage.jpg', sizingMethod='scale')"; /* To make IE work */

Comment: You don't. DX filter support was dropped in IE 10.

Comment: Why did you break context menu on that site?

Comment: @Quentin just wanted to add the reference and add that you're correct for later versions alike: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/hh801215(v=vs.85).aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue here is that the image is **not** a background image. From your code-

```
<img src="http://rubowarkitekter.dk/wp-content/uploads/2013/12/forside_carlsberg.jpg" class="home">
```

This is an image **element** and not a **background image** added in CSS.

What you should instead be doing is adding the background image either to the "body" element or to your div wrapper.

There are a number of recommendations I feel it important to make-

1. Use the HTML 5 doctype rather than XHTML transitional
2. Remove the oncontextmenu event handler on your body element - it **will not** prevent someone saving your images if they want to, but will annoy your users.
3. Validate your site, there are 33 errors on the home page - which will mean inconsistent results in browsers for your users. Your site does not work correctly in Google Chrome.
4. Organise your CSS, I cannot see that code you cited is actually exists in any of the loaded stylesheets (is it currently dev only?).
5. Where-ever you use vendor prefixes (the -moz, -webkit etc.) these should appear **before** the standard property (without the prefix) so that it is used instead of the vendor prefix once the property is supported by the browser.
6. Clear your floats by using something like the [CSS tricks clear-fix](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/clear-fix/) code. The social media widgets for example.
7. **Do not** use position:fixed or position:absolute for layout - you have not control over the viewport/device/window size your users are visiting on, so cannot assume a specific width.

Comment: The code is taken from the website cited by the OP at the time I began to answer this question. The image has since been removed and the site now appears broken in both Chrome and Internet Explorer 11.

Comment: Checking today the issue appears resolved and the image element has now been replaced with a background image on the body element.

Answer (score 1):

Chris Coyier of CSS-Tricks proposes 3 great solutions which works quite well, 2 of which being pure CSS.

[You can read up on this here](http://css-tricks.com/perfect-full-page-background-image)

## Examples

### Example 1 (fixed position -- ideal option)

```
img.bg {
  /* Set rules to fill background */
  min-height: 100%;
  min-width: 1024px;

  /* Set up proportionate scaling */
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;

  /* Set up positioning */
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 1024px) { /* Specific to this particular image */
  img.bg {
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -512px;   /* 50% */
  }
}
```

### Example 2 (inline image -- next best thing)

**HTML**

```
<div id="bg">
  <img src="images/bg.jpg" alt="">
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#bg {
  position: fixed; 
  top: -50%; 
  left: -50%; 
  width: 200%; 
  height: 200%;
}
#bg img {
  position: absolute; 
  top: 0; 
  left: 0; 
  right: 0; 
  bottom: 0; 
  margin: auto; 
  min-width: 50%;
  min-height: 50%;
}
```

### Example 3 (uses filters -- less recommended)

```
html { 
  background: url(images/bg.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; 
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;

  /* IE fallback support */
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(src='.myBackground.jpg', sizingMethod='scale');
  -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(src='myBackground.jpg', sizingMethod='scale')";
}
```

Comment: please try to include some relevant pieces of code. pure link answers are discouraged in the site

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: Sample Code added to review down votes and offer better reference in case of broken link, as suggested.

Comment: Downvoted as the IE fallback support is rather useless for IE10+ 
@PubliDesign use one of the other examples instead, the other 2 seems to be working quite well.