# Images max-width max-height not working in IE 11

Tags: html, css, fullpage.js

I use fullPage.js and the following html and css for the image slider on my website.

It works in Safari and Chrome on Mac but not in IE 11 on Windows.

Has anybody an idea how to fix this?

Demo: [www.aronsommer.com](http://www.aronsommer.com)

```
<div class="slide"><img src="images/bitumenpainting1.jpg" alt="Bitumenpainting 1"></div>

.slide img {
width : auto;
height : auto;
max-width : 90%;
max-height : 90%;
margin : 0 auto;
padding : 0;
display : block;
}
```

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20801411/background-image-height-width-doest-work-on-ie11

Comment: Thanks but I can not use a background image. I want to add more lazy loading images with <img data-src="image.png"> to the fullPage.js slider in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry. It's easier if you treat the CSS file. You need some CSS Hacks, it's something like the exemple bellow:

```
/* IE7 */
*:first-child+html #element { color: red } 

/* IE7, FF, Safari, Opera  */
html>body #elemento { color: red }

/* IE8, FF, Safari, Opera (Everything but IE 6,7) */
html>/**/ body #elemento { color: red }

/* Opera 9.27 and safari 2 */
html:first-child #element { color: red }

/* Safari 2-3 */
html[xmlns*=""] body:last-child #element { color: red }

/* safari 3+, chrome 1+, opera9+, ff 3.5+ */
body:nth-of-type(1) #element { color: red }

/* safari 3+, chrome 1+, opera9+, ff 3.5+ */
body:first-of-type #element {  color: red }

/* saf3+, chrome1+ */
@media screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:0) {
#element { color: red }
}

/* iPhone / mobile webkit */
@media screen and (max-device-width: 480px) {
#element { color: red }
}

/* Safari 2 - 3.1 */
html[xmlns*=""]:root #element { color: red }

/* Safari 2 - 3.1, Opera 9.25 */
*|html[xmlns*=""] #element { color: red }

/* Tudo menos IE6-8 */
:root *> #element { color: red }

/* IE7 */
*+html #element {  color: red }

/* Firefox 3.0+ */
#element,  x:-moz-any-link, x:default { color: red }
```

You need to change all your CSS to program with the browser compatibility.

I hope this helps

Comment: Thanks but this breaks everything.

Answer (score 0):

Following media query has fixed my problem with IE 11.

Using viewport units vw and vh instead of percentage for max-width and max-height.

```
@media screen and (-ms-high-contrast: active), (-ms-high-contrast: none) {
/* IE10+ specific styles go here */
.slide img {
max-width : 90vw;
max-height : 90vh;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a bug in IE11: [Bug Report](https://connect.microsoft.com/IE/Feedback/Details/1218984). Adding `flex: 1` (as in the report)

```
.slide img {
    flex: 1
    max-width: 100%
    max-height: 100%
}
```

Works for me. You may have to change your containers display mode to flexbox. Like so (example centers content):

```
.slide {
    display: flex
    align-items: center
    justify-content: center
    width: whateveryoulike
    height: whateveryoulike
}
```

Very nasty bug!

Comment: doesnt work for portrait images, though. excuse me enthusiastic.